# How to make an application look the same on another computer using WAMP

Tags: php, css, wamp, wampserver, remote-server

I have deployed a php application on wamp server. It looks fine on the same machine but when I try to access it from another machine, the look and feel looks disturbed. Previously it was not even accessible but I somehow got it working by changing the allow, deny permissions. But now the css is somewhat not coming same on the other machine.
Suggestions please.

Thank You
Sandeep

**Got it!**
In the config.php file of the app I put host as localhost becuase of which the remote machine was not able to find the css files.
Thanks for the help @nomaD and @tcole

Comment: When you view source, or try to go to the CSS directly - what happens? It sounds like you may be using absolute local URLs. Could you post a sample of the code? That would definitely help too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using something like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to look for differences in the HTTP request/response on both computers to see where the problem is, it's likely a permissions problem or an issue with the `src` attribute on your `<link />` elements.. You might also want to look in your browser's console log (in Chrome's Inspector or Firebug etc.)